# Creating a Live Streaming from Android (YouTube API)

Tags: android, youtube-api, live-streaming

I'm searching for the Android example shown at "Google I/O 2013 - Broadcast Yourself".
Is the one that shows how to create a broadcast directly from an android app.
I've search the youtube-api-samples, but this one is not included.

Comment: @Have you found anything yet?